# Merge multiple video files using ffmpeg by adding multiple compress options

Tags: ffmpeg, video-recording, codec, compression

I would like to merge multiple video files, performing in the same time complex compressing options.

How can I do that? The following ffmpeg command resulting this error:

```
 Filtergraph 'scale=1280:720,setpts=0.20*PTS' was specified through the -vf/-af/-filter option for output stream 0:0, which is fed from a complex filtergraph.
-vf/-af/-filter and -filter_complex cannot be used together for the same stream.
```

The ffmpeg command that i used:

```
ffmpeg -i GOPR0003.MP4 -i GOPR0004.MP4 -i GOPR0005.MP4 -i GOPR0005.MP4 -i GOPR0006.MP4 -i GOPR0007.MP4 -i GOPR0007.MP4 -i GOPR0008.MP4 -i GOPR0009.MP4 -i GOPR0010.MP4 -i GOPR0012.MP4 -i GOPR0013.MP4 -i GOPR0015.MP4 \
   -filter_complex "[0:v] [1:v] [2:v] [3:v] [4:v] [5:v] [6:v] [7:v] [8:v]  [9:v]  [10:v] concat=n=11:v=1 [v]" \
    -r 24 -crf 18  -vcodec libx264 -vb 20M -vf "scale=1280:720,setpts=0.20*PTS"  -an   -map "[v]"   video_output_01.avi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All filtering should be performed in the same filtergraph. Each `-filter_complex` or `-vf` defines a different filtergraph. You can use

```
-filter_complex "[0:v] [1:v] [2:v] [3:v] [4:v] [5:v] [6:v] [7:v] [8:v]  [9:v]  [10:v] concat=n=11:v=1,scale=1280:720,setpts=0.20*PTS [v]"
```

Comment: using `ffmpeg -i GOPR0009.MP4 -i GOPR0010.MP4 \
-filter_complex "[0:v] [1:v]  concat=n=2:v=1,vcodec=libx264,vb=20M,crf=14,r=32,scale=1280:720,setpts=0.20*PTS [v]" \
-map "[v]"   video_output_01.avi` gave this error: No such filter: 'vcodec'

Comment: and how can i add -fflags +genpts?

Comment: `vcodec=libx264,vb=20M,crf=14,r=32` --> none of these are filters. These all belong as `-key value` outside the filtergraph.

Comment: `-fflags +genpts` goes *before* each input to which you wish to apply it.

Comment: How can I transpose 180o degrees a video file while merging it? e.g. 

 `ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i VIDEOFILES_short.txt -filter_complex  \
  "[0:1] [v0]; \
   [1:1]vflip, hflip[v1];\
   [v0][v1]concat[out]" -map "[out]" -r 32 -crf 14  -vcodec libx264  -vb 20M   video_out_FF.avi`

Answer (score 0):

Finally, 
I used that command that resulted to compress multiple video files, while in the same time setting a range of compressing options in ffmpeg:

VIDEOFILES.txt contains a list of the videos that are to merged in a specific way:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i VIDEOFILES.txt -r 32 -crf 14  -vcodec libx264 -vb 20M -vf "scale=1280:720,setpts=0.20*PTS" -fflags +genpts  -an   video_output.avi
```